# How to get username inside spark submit task in databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, environment-variables, databricks

I'm trying to retrieve the user name inside spark-submit task in Databricks to write additional information to the table about a user who was changing the data. Unfortunately, I'm not able to find the correct way.
For now, I was trying two things:

`spark.sparkContext.sparkUser`

and

`System.getProperty("user.name")`

but they both return `root`.
Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Delta Lake tables, then information about performed operations is captured in the history of the Delta Lake table - see an example in the [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html#history-schema).

Databricks exposes a lot of information via `spark.conf` - the configuration properties are starting with `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.`, so you can filter all configurations and search for necessary information.

But you need to take into account that all operations in the job are performed under identity of the job owner, even if it's triggered by someone else.

There is a `spark.databricks.clusterUsageTags.clusterAllTags` configuration property that contains a JSON string containing a list of cluster tags, that also include `Owner` field with email of user who owns that Databricks job.